# What is Shoshana Damari's voice called?

Tags: voice

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w32ZghiVSgI) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHq3bb4J1Ww) are some samples of Shoshana Damari's singing. She was famous, among other things, for her very distinctive voice.

Her voice is lower than a mezzo. Would that be a contralto? Or is the classification inappropriate at all, considering she was not a classical singer?

Answer (score 1):

I would say she is a contralto or lyric alto. It is not inappropriate to classify singers like that even though they do not sing classical music.
My voice teacher has a lot of pop singers who are lyric altos according to her. She also says that a lyric alto is generally not a recognized voice type but she has a lot of students whose voice type is exactly that.